# When validating, the location of the error on the same page shows (type = Bad Request, status = 400)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I want to check the registration field for validation. And it works for me, but if the user enters something wrong, then I get a page with (type = Bad Request, status = 400) and should knock out an SMS with an error in the form itself. what am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column
@Size(min=2, max=25, message = "от 2 до 25 символов")
@NotNull
private String username;

@Column
@NotNull
private String password;

@Transient
@Column
private String passwordConfirm;

@Column
private String eMail;

public User(){}

public User(String username, String password, String passwordConfirm, String eMail) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    this.eMail = eMail;
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST) //@ModelAttribute("userForm")
public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, @RequestParam String username,
                      @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String passwordConfirm,
                      @RequestParam String email, Model model, Errors errors) {

    if(errors.hasErrors()){
       return "/registration";
    } else {
        User user = new User(username, password, passwordConfirm, email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setPasswordConfirm(passwordConfirm);
        user.setEMail(email);
        userService.saveUser(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    }

    }
```

and html

```
<div class="row main-form">
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${userForm}" modelAttribute="userForm">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Ваш Логин</label>
            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}" name="username"   id="username" placeholder="Введите ваш логин"/>
                    <span class="validationError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}" ></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I really have no idea why it doesn't show the same registration page but with an error.At the same time, in the logs of the idea, it shows me this error and the message error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the Spring documentation when describing the `Errors` an `BindingResult' [method arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) (emphasis mine):

> For access to errors from validation and data binding for a command object (that is, a `@ModelAttribute` argument) or errors from the validation of a `@RequestBody` or `@RequestPart` arguments. *You must declare an `Errors`, or `BindingResult` argument immediately after the validated method argument.*

Please, modify your method as follows (please, note the position of the `Errors` parameter):

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST) //@ModelAttribute("userForm")
public String addUser(
  @Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm,
  Errors errors,
  @RequestParam String username,
  @RequestParam String password,
  @RequestParam String passwordConfirm,
  @RequestParam String email,
  Model model
) {

    if(errors.hasErrors()){
       return "/registration";
    } else {
        User user = new User(username, password, passwordConfirm, email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setPasswordConfirm(passwordConfirm);
        user.setEMail(email);
        userService.saveUser(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You are welcome Deniss. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.